# i m confused which tech i used asp.mvc or wcf for my project

Tags: asp.net

I have basic knowledge of asp.net and i want develop the project.So m confused between Wcf and asp.mvc which is good for my project. i read description of both but cant get solution. could someone please help me as soon as possible.

project description- collection of data from different site(location) through wireless communication(gprs communication) and store the data on oracle 10G. and i want show the history reports and trends .
how i show reports? like in windows application (crystal report and rdlc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WCF` is rest service while `asp.net MVC` is web development technique. So if you want expose services then you can move `WCF` or `WEB API` else will move to `ASP.NET MVC`.

Comment: sir according to my project desc i think asp.mvc is useful ? is it?

Comment: Right, MVC is useful to you. If this information is useful then mark as accepted